# NLog: log serialized object as message

Tags: c#, nlog

I've set nlog.config like this to create my logs as JSON

```
<target name='JsonFile' type='File' fileName='${basedir}/logs/nlog-${shortdate}.json'>
   <layout type='JsonLayout'>
      <attribute name='time' layout='${longdate}' />
      <attribute name='level' layout='${level:upperCase=true}'/>
      <attribute name='nested' encode='false'  >
         <layout type='JsonLayout'>
            <attribute name='message' layout='${message}' encode='true' />
            <attribute name='exception' layout='${exception}' />
         </layout>
      </attribute>
   </layout>
</target>
```

Logging senario:

```
public class MessageResult {
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public string IsSuccess { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller {
   private readonly ILogger _logger;
   *** Dependency injection for ILogger ***

   public IActionResult Index() {
      var message = new MessageResult() {
         Message = "Json test message",
         IsSuccess = true
      };
      var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
      _logger.LogWarning(json);

      return View();
   }
}
```

and what has logged is this:

```
{ "time": "2020-10-08 20:12:35.6472", "level": "WARN", "nested": { "message": "{\"Message\":\"Json test message\",\"IsSuccess\":true}" } }
```

but I wanted to log the message as JSON as well not as string like what I've got
so what do I have to do for it?

Comment: You can use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/).
Serilog is a moder logger framework.Serilog provides structured logging by default.
You can use JsonFormatter for output and even write your customized formatter (json,yaml,xml,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the JSON Serialization upfront, then I would let the logging framework do it. By changing from this:

```
  var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
  _logger.LogWarning(json);
```

Into this:

```
  _logger.LogWarning("{@message}", message);
```

And use this as config:

```
<target name='JsonFile' type='File' fileName='${basedir}/logs/nlog-${shortdate}.json'>
   <layout type='JsonLayout'>
      <attribute name='time' layout='${longdate}' />
      <attribute name='level' layout='${level:upperCase=true}'/>
      <attribute name='nested' encode='false'>
         <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true">
            <attribute name='messagetemplate' layout='${message:raw=true}' />
            <attribute name='exception' layout='${exception}' />
         </layout>
      </attribute>
   </layout>
</target>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: thanks, it solves the main problem, but what has logged is:

`{ "time": "2020-10-10 08:48:42.0724", "level": "WARN", "nested": { "message": "{@message}", "message": {"Message":"Json test message", "IsSuccess":true} } }`


is there any way to log this:

`{ "time": "2020-10-10 08:48:42.0724", "level": "WARN", "nested": { "message": {"Message":"Json test message", "IsSuccess":true} } }`

Comment: @reza.mohseni Think you just have to remove JsonLayout-attribute with `layout='${message:raw=true}'`

Comment: No name parameter is required

Comment: @reza.mohseni Sorry I don't understand.